# Integrals for Calculus 2

Tags: geometry

Evaluate the integral by interpreting it in terms of areas. In other words, draw a picture of the region the integral represents, and find the area using high school geometry.

$$\int_0^4 |2x-5| dx$$

Comment: So where is your picture? or what areas did you find?

Answer (score 4):

Given below I have draw the Graph of $y=|2x-5|$ and $x=0$ and $x=4$ and then calculate area of bounded region

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We know for real $a,|a|=a$ if $a\ge0$ and $|a|=-a$ if $a<0$

So, $|2x-5|=2x-5$ if $2x-5\ge 0\implies x\ge 2.5$ and $|2x-5|=-(2x-5)=5-2x$ if $2x-5<0\implies x<2.5$

So, $$\int_{0}^{4}|2x-5|dx=\int_0^{2.5}(2x-5)dx+\int_{2.5}^{4}(5-2x)dx=(x^2-5x)_0^{2.5}-(x^2-5x)_{2.5}^4$$

Answer (score 1):

The area (integral) consists of two triangles.

The line $y=2x-5$ crosses the $x$-axis at $(\frac{5}{2},0)$.

The value (height) at $0$ is $-5$ and at $4$ is $3$.
So the first triangle has area $\frac{1}{2}\frac{5}{2}\cdot 5=\frac{25}{4}$ and the second $\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{2}\cdot 3=\frac{9}{4}$. Therefore
$$\int_{0}^{4}|2x-5|dx=\frac{25}{4}+\frac{9}{4}=\frac{34}{4}=\frac{17}{2}$$

Comment: You might change the second triangle the $\frac{3}{5}$ should be $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Thank you; I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

$f(0)=5$ and $f(4)=3$ and $2.5$ is a root of this function. Calculate the integrals over these intervals $[0.2.5], [2.5,4]$ and add the integrals. You get $\frac{25}{4} +\frac{9}{4}$. [image]

Comment: I edited your answer. Hopefully I didn't change the meaning.